# I don't know why there's no big performance difference between JS and Go in my case

Tags: javascript, performance, go

I've just solved the [#12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12) problem in Project Euler, about divisor and triangle number, once in Go and once in JavaScript. I thought the code in Go would be much faster than one in JS, cause JS runs the code in runtime and Go builds the code. I know that building the code doesn't directly mean good performance, but the result was that even the code in JS was sometimes faster in different conditions.

The code I used is like below.

https://gist.github.com/noraesae/675e40477e177f9f63f9

I tested them in my macbook, and spec is like below.

Processor: 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

I ran them with commands below.

> $ #js
> $ node euler12.js
>
> $ #go
> $ go build euler12.go
> $ ./euler12

Did I do something wrong? If not, why there's no difference between them? I also tested with Python and there was a big gap between Go and Python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is exactly the same code, one gets compiled by the Go compiler, the other by the JIT of the Javascript VM. So: Why do you expect major differences on synthetic, artificial code?

Comment: Very true, and thanks for mentioning JIT as I've not noticed it. Though, Go is a low-level and static-typed language, compared with JavaScript, and I thought that there might be some performance advantages. Also I thought interpreting process might not be needed for Go, which made me expect Go being faster. Was I thinking wrong?

Comment: And it is not the same code, despite what the shape of the code looks like.  Specifically: the types are different.  One is dealing with floating point doubles implicitly in the JavaScript case, and the Go code is using `int64`s.  Since the numeric type is implicit in JavaScript, some evaluators will switch type representations underneath the surface when it can tell that it can use a cheaper representation.  For example, V8 will use 31-bit small integers when it knows the numbers aren't that large.  http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/

Answer (score 1):

Pretty interesting, on my machine (macbookpro late 2013, i7  2.3ghz), the JS code is much faster than the Go one:

JS:

```
time node test.js
842161320

real    0m4.437s
user    0m4.900s
sys     0m0.150s
```

Go:

```
time GOMAXPROCS=8 ./test
842161320

real    0m7.345s
user    0m7.470s
sys     0m0.010s
```

However, after a quick optimization of the Go code:

Go:

```
time GOMAXPROCS=8 ./test
842161320

real    0m1.760s
user    0m11.610s
sys     0m0.230s
```

The quick optimization I am talking about (very naive): parallelize your computation:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "runtime"
)

func numberOfDevisor(n int64) int64 {
        var result int64

        var i int64 = 1
        for true {
                if n%i == 0 {
                        opposite := n / i
                        if opposite == i {
                                result++
                                return result
                        } else if opposite > i {
                                result += 2
                        } else {
                                return result
                        }
                }
                i++
        }
        return result
}

func main() {
        var acc int64
        var i int64 = 1

        maxRoutines := runtime.NumCPU()
        c := make(chan struct{}, maxRoutines)
        for i := 0; i < maxRoutines; i++ {
                c <- struct{}{}
        }
        for true {
                <-c
                acc += i
                go func(acc int64) {
                        defer func() { c <- struct{}{} }()
                        if numberOfDevisor(acc) > 1000 {
                                fmt.Println(acc)
                                os.Exit(0)
                        }
                }(acc)
                i++
        }
}
```